# Displaying a persons Initials in capitals from they name they have entered

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to get this output from the program.

> Write a program which asks the users to enter their full name and then displays, in uppercase, the first initial of each name, separated by full stops.

So far I have the following program written:

```
def main():

    name=input("Please Enter Your Name: ")
    name_split = name.split()
    print(name_split)
    for line in name_split:
        print(line[0][0].upper())

main()
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems you want a simple String concatenation, you could write it like this:

```
outputStr = ""
for line in name_split:
    outputStr = outputStr + line[0][0].upper() + '.'

print outputStr
```

If you only want a '.' between letters, you could write it like this:

```
print '.'.join([c[0].upper() for c in name_split])
```

This will only put dots between each letter.